# Clean up string data before saving in database as integer

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have an integer column called `dollars` in my database table and I am attempting to save values such as `$1000` in the database. However, attempting to save the string `$1000` with the dollar sign in an integer column will cause an automatic conversion to the integer `0`.

To prevent this from happening, I tried to add a `before_save` callback to my `clean_data` method in my model to remove the dollar sign. But it seems that rails has already attempted to save the entire `$1000` string in the database before `clean_data` is called.

I wonder if there is a better way to remove the dollar sign from the values before saving to the database as an integer?

Here's my code:

In the `create` action of the `bids_controller.rb`, doing this will allow the database to save the value `$1000` from the form properly:

```
    # Remove dollar sign
    if params[:bid][:dollars][0] == "$"
      params[:bid][:dollars] = params[:bid][:dollars].delete('$')
    end

    @bid = Bid.new(params[:bid])
    @bid.save
```

However, if I were to remove the if-end fragment from the controller and clean the data in the `Bid` model, like this:

```
    before_save :clean_data

    def clean_data
      puts self.dollars
      self.dollars = self.dollars.delete('$')
    end
```

I will get the value `0` for `puts self.dollars` before the `clean_data` method has a chance to remove the dollar sign.

My hypothesis is that rails has attempted to "hold" the data in the database before either `clean_data` or `save` is called, and this "hold" causes the data to be converted to `0` since the integer column isn't able to save the dollar sign.

Thank you very much for your help! :)

Comment: Please show your code in the question because it sounds like you're doing it well.

Comment: Hi, I just updated my question to include the code. Thanks for helping!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I strip dollar signs from a value before validation in Rails?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11084718/how-do-i-strip-dollar-signs-from-a-value-before-validation-in-rails)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the `tr` method.

```
"$1000".tr("$", "") # => "1000"
```

You should be able to do this on the string variable prior to saving it to the database.

Comment: Yeaps. I just updated my question to include the code. I think my `.delete('$')` has the same effect as `.tr`. Thanks!