# How do I strip dollar signs from a value before validation in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Here's what I'm using in my model:

```
before_validation :strip_dollar_sign

validates :amount_due,
          :format => { :with => /^\d+??(?:\.\d{0,2})?$/ }, 
          :numericality => {:greater_than => 0}

private

def strip_dollar_sign
  self.amount_due = self.amount_due.to_s.tr!('$,','').to_f
end
```

If I run the line from the strip_dollar_sign function by hand in the Rails Console I get exactly what I want (i.e. $400 ends up as 400.0) but when I use the actual form in my app the value always ends up as 0.0. Anybody catch what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: money should not be stored as floats, but as decimal in the database and BigDecimal in ruby.   Floats can have rounding errors which might cause unexpected results.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Three problems here:

- As pointed out by Stefan in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11084776/211563), you may want to remove the `,` in your `tr!` call, though it won't affect the replacement of a `$`.
- You're using `tr!`, and are using its return value in an incorrect way. `tr!` (along with most of Ruby's `!` method variants) mutates the string in-place and returns `nil` if no changes were made. Since `nil.to_f` is `0.0`, that's why you're getting that (or maybe not, see below). You should instead use `tr`.
- Rails automatically converts assignment arguments to the correct type for the database column associated with it, so even before validation your value is being converted to a float, and `"$400".to_f` is `0.0`, and that's what your callback sees. The solution is to override `amount_due=` instead of using a callback:

  ```
  def amount_due=(value)
    value = value.to_s.tr('$', '').to_f
    write_attribute(:amount_due, value)
  end
  ```

Comment: Actually the comma in the `tr` call is fine (if also probably unwanted): `"$500".tr("$,", '')`. To quote the docs: "Returns a copy of str with the characters in from_str replaced by the corresponding characters in to_str. If to_str is shorter than from_str, it is padded with its last character in order to maintain the correspondence."

Comment: @MichaelKohl Good point, edited to note that it doesn't affect the replacement of the `$`, though it may still be unwanted since a comma is a delimiter in some locales (plus the OP seems to have implied in Stefan's answer that is was an error).

Comment: I think you're on to something here, but something else is still broken. If I go in the console and run `amount_due = "$400"` and then `amount_due.to_s.tr('$', '').to_f` the output is `400.0`. But if I create an object and try to assign the same `$400` to the `.amount_due` value, I still get `0.0`.

Comment: @richrad Ah I think I know what's happening, see my updated answer.

Comment: We have a winner! I would have been scratching my head a long time before I figured that one out. Thanks!

Comment: That's it. @richrad you should save that column as a `Decimal` with fixed precision and scale.

Answer (score 3):

There's a comma after `$` so you're removing `$,` instead of `$`.

Comment: Good catch! But it still spits out 0.0.

Answer (score -2):

I recommend doing this in javascript. Rails seems to do some magic with form helpers that will convert any non-numeric value in a field that is backed by a numeric database type to 0.0. Stupid, I know.

Comment: OP is asking for solutions in Rails (as you may see the tags) so JS not a answer to his question.